# Python 2.7.3 mis-ordered dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having troubles in getting an ordered dict with Python 2.7.3. The first two examples behave as expected, the third one returns a mis-ordered dict, although the logic is the same (I tried with other value than '*' and got the same result):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d={}
>>> for k in [1, 6, 5, 2]:
...   d[k]='*'
... 
>>> d
{1: '*', 2: '*', 5: '*', 6: '*'}
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> for k in [1, 2, 5, 6]:
...   d[k]='*'
... 
>>> d
{1: '*', 2: '*', 5: '*', 6: '*'}
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> for k in [1001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005, 3006, 3007, 3008, 3009, 3010, 4001, 4002, 4003, 4005, 4006, 4007, 4008, 4010, 4011, 4012, 4013, 4241, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 5025, 5030, 5031, 5032, 5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5038, 5039, 5040, 5041, 5241]:
...   d[k]='*'
... 
>>> d
{5035: '*', 5001: '*', 5002: '*', 5003: '*', 5004: '*', 5005: '*', 5006: '*', 5007: '*', 5008: '*', 4241: '*', 5010: '*', 5011: '*', 5012: '*', 5013: '*', 5014: '*', 5015: '*', 5016: '*', 5017: '*', 5018: '*', 5024: '*', 4001: '*', 4002: '*', 4003: '*', 4005: '*', 4006: '*', 4007: '*', 4008: '*', 5033: '*', 4010: '*', 4011: '*', 4012: '*', 4013: '*', 5038: '*', 5039: '*', 5040: '*', 5041: '*', 3001: '*', 3002: '*', 3003: '*', 3004: '*', 3005: '*', 3006: '*', 3007: '*', 3008: '*', 3009: '*', 3010: '*', 5025: '*', 5036: '*', 2001: '*', 2002: '*', 2003: '*', 2004: '*', 2005: '*', 2006: '*', 2007: '*', 2008: '*', 2009: '*', 5037: '*', 5030: '*', 5009: '*', 1001: '*', 5031: '*', 5032: '*', 5241: '*', 5034: '*'}
>>> d.keys()
[5035, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 5006, 5007, 5008, 4241, 5010, 5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5024, 4001, 4002, 4003, 4005, 4006, 4007, 4008, 5033, 4010, 4011, 4012, 4013, 5038, 5039, 5040, 5041, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005, 3006, 3007, 3008, 3009, 3010, 5025, 5036, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 5037, 5030, 5009, 1001, 5031, 5032, 5241, 5034]
```

Is there any reason for this ?
Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Yes, dicts are unordered by definition.

Comment: If you want an ordered dict, use `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score -1):

dictionaries in python are unordered objects.
you can use ordered dictionaries if you like:
[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. My mistake was to think (based on the first 2 examples I gave) that the items insertion order into the dict was preserved, which is not the case.